# How to get following nodes name in xPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I would like to get the name of the following nodes in my xPath function.

My XML (example):

```
<TEXT>
    <TITLE>AAA</TITLE>
    <SUB_TITLE>SUB</SUB_TITLE>
    <SUB_TITLE>SUB</SUB_TITLE>
    <SUB_TITLE2>SUB2</SUB_TITLE2>

    <TITLE>BBB</TITLE
    ...
</TEXT>
```

In my database, SUB_TITLE and SUB_TITLE2 are linked in the TITLE table. But, in the XML file, they aren't linked. These are just node after node...

I tried to write a PHP function like that:

```
function get_next(SimpleXMLElement $node)
    return $node->xpath('following::*name()');
```

In order to get the name of the following node, and then, I could write a loop, to group my TITLE.

```
while (get_next($param)!='TITLE')
    // operation
```

So, how can I get all the name of the nodes following my param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know xpath() function can only return nodes. You can use [getName()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) function instead to get a node name, for example :

```
function get_next(SimpleXMLElement $node){
    $result = [];
    foreach($node->xpath('following-sibling::*') as $sibling){
        $result[] = $sibling->getName();
    }
    return $result;
}
```